# Use Windows 7 PC as internet filter for home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking

I would like to use an old Windows 7 box as a filter for my internet traffic. I'd like it to serve as the DHCP server as well so that I don't have to manually setup a proxy/gateway info on all my home network computers.

Does anyone know software to handle this? If I have k9 internet filter installed and manage to route all my traffic through that computer, will it do the trick?

Any tips/suggestions are welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to use an old Windows 7 box as a filter for my internet traffic

I use [Untangle's Lite Package](http://www.untangle.com/) along with [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/). Both are free!